# Правильно ли составлен заголовок к статье?

Tags: словообразование, недопустимая-метка

Брак - это самые трудные из всех человеческих отношений

Comment: Исходное предложение должно быть правильно согласовано: "Брак - это самое трудное из всех человеческих отношений" (из чисто формальных соображений; я не беру во внимание смысловое значение предложения)

Comment: Брак - это "отношения" в значении "связи между кем-, чем-л., образующиеся в процессе общения, какой-л. деятельности" (только мн. число!). А ваше предложение можно прочитать как "самое трудное отношение" (ед. число).

Comment: По-Вашему, это согласовано?
Получается: брак - это отношение (ед.ч.)
Самое трудное отношение из всех человеческих?

Answer (score 2):

Можно назвать так: "Брак как самый трудный вид человеческих отношений".

Предлагаемый вариант "Брак - это самые трудные из всех человеческих отношений" мне кажется неверным из-за отсутствия согласования по роду и числу, причем это та  несочетаемость, которая бросается в глаза  и поэтому вряд ли допустима.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, неудачная формулировка, предложение не согласовано. 
Можно перефразировать: "Супружеские отношения - самые сложные из всех" (например).

Answer (score 0):

Нет, так заголовок не читается. Дело в том, что любой заголовок не должен являть собой законченную мысль. Напротив, его задача быть недосказанным, чтобы заставить читателя ознакомиться со статьей. Поэтому лучше избегать таких вот декларативных заявлений. Например, можно сказать, например, "Брак как самые сложные из человеческих отношений". Или более завлекательное: "Брак. Что может быть сложнее?"

Comment: По мне, так все эти заголовки плохи. Слово брак - как удар молотком... в общем, не советую его использовать.

Comment: ну и слово брак не согласовано со словом "отношения". Ед. ч. vs мн. ч.  Короче, придумайте другое.

Comment: >ну и слово брак не согласовано со словом "отношения".  
   
Ему и не надо быть согласованным.

Comment: Некоторые очень любят хаять чужое, при этом не пытаясь предложить лучше. Да, я согласна, что "брак" и "отношения" не очень согласуются, но претензии не ко мне. Если Вы, уважаемый(мая) Кристабелл, не заметили, автор вопроса задал изначальный вариант заголовка, нарушать который нужно было в минимальном объеме. А мои варианты неплохи - я же не знаю содержание статьи, поэтому предложила несколько с разной окраской.  
И, кстати, надо писать "слово "брак", взяв его в кавычки. Это к сведению.

Comment: А кавычки зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу причин ставить "самые трудные" во множественном. 
Грамматически это не запрещено (шашлык - это кусочки мяса на вертеле), но здесь именно *смыслового* наполнения нет. Почему обязательно "отношения"? 
Касательно того, каким должен быть заголовок - это не совсем ко мне, но мне кажется, что Fuchoin Kazuki излишне придирчива. Любой заголовок сойдет, коли на него внимание обращают.